# function variable in struct resets to nil

Tags: go

I'm trying to make HTTP proxy using go net/http. I made struct type named HTTPProxy to store http.Server object and some hooks to modify Request and Response.

There're two hooks in my proxy(Request/Response hook). The hooks can be set with interface named `SetRequestHook` and `SetResultHook`. I checked value of `HTTPProxy` struct using `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", httpProxy)` before/after SetRequestHook to check the set of request hook was successful. This is the value of `httpProxy` before/after `SetRequestHook`.

```
webproxy.HTTPProxy{server:(*http.Server)(0xc000154000), IsStarted:false, requestHook:(webproxy.RequestHookFunc)(nil), responseHook:(webproxy.ResponseHookFunc)(nil)}
webproxy.HTTPProxy{server:(*http.Server)(0xc000154000), IsStarted:false, requestHook:(webproxy.RequestHookFunc)(0x75ce60), responseHook:(webproxy.ResponseHookFunc)(nil)}
```

As you can see address of request hook function stored well in `httpProxy` struct. But if I call another interface names `Start` requestHook in struct resets to nil for no reason. This is the result of `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", httpProxy)` in `Start` interface.

```
webproxy.HTTPProxy{server:(*http.Server)(0xc000154000), IsStarted:false, requestHook:(webproxy.RequestHookFunc)(nil), responseHook:(webproxy.ResponseHookFunc)(nil)}
```

I haven't reset my struct since initialize so I'm not even sure what is happening to my struct. How can I make my request hook to not reset to nil? This is my current code having this problem.

- cmd/runserver/main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "test/pkg/webproxy"
)

var a int

func test(request *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("New Request: %d\n", a)
    a++
}

func main() {
    a = 1
    httpProxy := webproxy.NewHTTPProxy()
    httpProxy.SetRequestHook(test)
    httpProxy.Start("", 3000)
}
```

- pkg/webproxy/webproxy.go

```golang
// Package webproxy provides http and https proxy with request and response hooks
package webproxy

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
)

// RequestHookFunc typed functions provided to proxy will modify request before sent to the server.
type RequestHookFunc func(request *http.Request)

// ResponseHookFunc typed functions provided to proxy will modify response before sent to the client.
type ResponseHookFunc func(response *http.Response)

// HTTPProxy will store some items that are used in HTTP proxy and state.
type HTTPProxy struct {
    server       *http.Server
    IsStarted    bool
    requestHook  RequestHookFunc
    responseHook ResponseHookFunc
}

// ProxyManager provide methods to manage HTTPProxy and HTTPSProxy.
type ProxyManager interface {
    Start(host string, port uint16)
    Stop()
    GetAddr()
    SetRequestHook(hook RequestHookFunc)
    SetResponseHook(hook ResponseHookFunc)
}

// NewHTTPProxy creates default HTTPProxy struct.
func NewHTTPProxy() *HTTPProxy {
    return &HTTPProxy{
        server:       new(http.Server),
        IsStarted:    false,
        requestHook:  nil,
        responseHook: nil,
    }
}

// Start serves HTTPProxy on host:port.
func (httpProxy HTTPProxy) Start(host string, port uint16) {
    if httpProxy.IsStarted {
        log.Println("[HTTP] The proxy is already running.")
        return
    } else if len(host) != 0 && net.ParseIP(host) == nil {
        log.Fatal("[HTTP] Inserted host is not valid.")
    }

    addr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", httpProxy) // requestHook = nil. Why?? I called SetRequestHook before run Start
    httpProxy.server.Handler = getHandler(httpProxy.requestHook, httpProxy.responseHook)
    httpProxy.server.Addr = addr

    log.Printf("[HTTP] The proxy will be served on %s:%d\n", host, port)
    if err := httpProxy.server.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Fatalf("[HTTP] The proxy ListenAndServer: %v\n", err)
    }
}

// Stop will stop HTTPProxy immediately.
func (httpProxy HTTPProxy) Stop() {
    if !httpProxy.IsStarted {
        log.Println("[HTTP] The proxy is not running.")
        return
    }
    httpProxy.server.Shutdown(context.Background())
}

// GetAddr will return HTTPProxy's host:port.
func (httpProxy HTTPProxy) GetAddr() string {
    return httpProxy.server.Addr
}

// SetRequestHook setup request hook into the proxy
func (httpProxy HTTPProxy) SetRequestHook(hook RequestHookFunc) {
    if httpProxy.IsStarted {
        log.Println("[HTTP] You can't set request hook while the proxy is working.")
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", httpProxy) // requestHook = nil
    httpProxy.requestHook = hook
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", httpProxy) // requestHook = [hook's address]
}

// SetResponseHook setup response hook into the proxy.
func (httpProxy HTTPProxy) SetResponseHook(hook ResponseHookFunc) {
    if httpProxy.IsStarted {
        log.Println("[HTTP] You can't set response hook while the proxy is working.")
        return
    }
    httpProxy.responseHook = hook
}
```

- pkg/webproxy/proxyhandler.go

```golang
package webproxy

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

type proxyHandler struct {
    requestHook  RequestHookFunc
    responseHook ResponseHookFunc
}

func getHandler(requestHookIn RequestHookFunc, responseHookIn ResponseHookFunc) http.Handler {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", requestHookIn)
    return &proxyHandler{requestHook: requestHookIn, responseHook: responseHookIn}
}

// ServeHttp
func (handler *proxyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", handler.requestHook)
    if handler.requestHook != nil {
        fmt.Println("Yaha")
        handler.requestHook(r)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    io.WriteString(w, "This HTTP response has both headers before this text and trailers at the end.\n")
}
```

Comment: Use pointer receivers for HTTPProxy methods, e.g. `func (httpProxy *HTTPProxy) SetResponseHook()`.

Comment: Good Lord. You are my Savior @BurakSerdar. I was stuck for about an hour because of this problem. I know exactly on now how to use interface. Thanks again.